# Xcode 12 how to add an existing project to a workspace

Tags: ios, xcode12

I cannot believe how hard this is. Perhaps because the word 'workspace' is overloaded by Apple and perhaps because the UI keeps changing every version. For a newbie to iOS, Xcode and Apple it's a nightmare.

- I have Xcode 12
- I have created a project.
- I used **File**/**save as
  workspace** to create a workspace to (eventually) hold multiple
  projects.
- Gave it a name.
- I have another already created project (a
  static library) that I would like to add to this workspace.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it. I see things for
previous Xcode versions but those UI options are not present in 12.

In the end I want to have a workspace where I have a demo project that uses the static library project for Bluetooth LE communications. I will be spending 90% of my time developing the BT library so I want to be able to access the source of both projects.

By the way, I am not using Storyboards. Not sure if that makes a difference, but just in case!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try?
https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-create-xcode-workspace-and-add-new-exist-project-into-it/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by

1. Close the project to add in Xcode
2. Drag the existing.xcodeproj file (one you closed) from Finder to Xcode and drop it next to existing sources/projects in the workspace

Xcode settings are often painful for even seasoned developers.  And every update seems to break something.

Comment: thanks for the help but I can't validate at the moment as my mini mac is trashed by a non-existent apple id. Will give it a try upon resurrection...

Comment: Closing the project is the key here. Hassled with it almost 2 hours before reading this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it just doesn't seem possible.
The only option seems to be to create the workspace in XCode 11 add the projects there then open in XCode 12

Comment: I can't validate if your answer is true as my mac mini is trashed from a non-existent apple id. I will revisit this sometime in the future, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a Workspace (i.e. a *.xcworkspace* file) ready to go, all you need to do is:

1. Close your project
2. Open your Workspace
3. Go to File > Add Files to "<your_workspace_name>"...
4. Select your existing project
5. Xcode will duplicate the references to your files, so you manually have to go to the Project navigator (shortcut: ⌘ + 1), select the duplicated references (they'll be at your Workspace's root) and delete them (select Remove Reference, *not* Move to Trash)
6. Enjoy your Workspace!

For good measure, select your scheme (most times it'll become available immediately, but sometimes you'll need to restart Xcode), build, and run your project to verify that everything went well.

Verified in Xcode 13.